# How would you optimize this query

Tags: sql, optimization, visual-foxpro

I'm in VFP9 (Yep, I know) the next query works perfectly, but with a DBF (Table) with a size of 20mb (or 9k of rows) create on the cursor a temp file larger than 2gb (and this crashes VFP9 for being 32bits)

```
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.*;
            FROM t1,t2;
            WHERE ALLTRIM(t1.name) = ALLTRIM(t2.name);
            AND ALLTRIM(t1.name2) = ALLTRIM(t2.name2);
            AND t1.tyc = t2.tyc;
            AND t1.nc = t2.nc;
            AND t1.forced = 0;
            AND t1.secuence NOT in (Select secuence FROM t2);   
            Into Cursor cursordel
```

I only put this fragment of code because works, except when I have more than 2k of rows
I thought that replacing that "not in" with a join would do the trick, but didnt work or at least the ways that I've tried...

Comment: On a side note: You could probably avoid `ALLTRIM` in your queries by updating all rows in the tables with `ALLTRIM` once and installing triggers that do the same for any inserted or updated row.

Comment: The query is looking for all t1 where there is a match in t2 on tyc, nc and the names, but no match in t2 for the sequence. *Maybe* its real purpose is to check whether there exists a match in t2 on tyc, nc and the names, but with another sequence. Well, maybe and maybe not. I cannot know that of course. If it is the case, you'd only need one lookup instead of two. Apart from this, follow Gordon's suggestion to use `EXISTS` for lookups and provide the indexes he mentions.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, updating all rows with alltrim() would be a meaningless operation, unless it is meant to be LTRIM() - which is unlikely.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: I don't understand why this would be meaningless. `ALLTRIM` removes leading and trailing spaces in FoxPro. Why would you want those in names anyway? If they are always removed by triggers right away (plus once per update for the existing data), `ALLTRIM` would no longer be needed in queries, and one might even provide useful indexes on these columns for faster lookup then.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, it is meaningless because OP says VFP and DBF in his question. Although, VFP has support for Varchar (not really), 99.999% of DBF have character fields as Char fields, not Varchar fields. That means ALLTRIM() just means LTRIM() and still resultant text is the same with trailing spaces. IOW, it doesn't help you remove trailing spaces in stored data. I believe, OP's use of ALLTRIM() had no purpose in fact (probably he wanted to make sure there is an exact match, which he could simply do it with == or setting ANSI ON). I don't want something in names, I prefer indexes be used.

Comment: You are doing it wrong using alltrim() but anyway it is your fault, not VFP's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the first table does not have duplicates, I would phrase this as `not exists`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t2
                  WHERE ALLTRIM(t1.name) = ALLTRIM(t2.name) AND
                        ALLTRIM(t1.name2) = ALLTRIM(t2.name2) AND
                        t1.tyc = t2.tyc AND
                        t1.nc = t2.nc
                ) AND
      t1.forced = 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t2
                  WHERE t2.secuence = t1.secuence
                 );
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on `t2(tyc, nc, name, name2)`, and `t2(secuence)`.  I doubt an index on `t1(forced)` would help, unless that column is very rarely `0`.

Even without the indexes, this eliminates the outer `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Note that your `NOT IN` condition on `t2` looks suspicious.  Why does it not need the matching criteria as well?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Yes, the first table doesn't have duplicates, neither the second, I note that is a very strange query, but is a query inside a large code and methods that works, I dont write this, is not my code, but Im working on it. This seems to work very well, I have to do some others tests but seems to go well, thanks! I'll mark as answer when I'm sure.

Comment: I have a problem, though that was a minor problem but I cant solve it, when I use this solution, says "error correlating fields", but if I remove the two strings on the where clause (name and name2) it works, but IDK yet if alter the result of the global procedure, u know what can cause this error?

Comment: @Synystter . . . You might need to do what component with a `LEFT JOIN`, alas.

Comment: I think the original query is looking for all t1 where there is a match in t2 on tyc, nc and the names, but no match in t2 for the sequence. Your first `NOT EXISTS` should be an `EXISTS` hence.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, if you use ALLTRIM(), then you don't need indexes for those fields, since they wouldn't be used anyway, no? He doesn't actually give all the details (that is the table structures and indexes) that is needed for optimization. By a guess, ALLTRIM()s were meant to be RTRIM() which are useless and prevents usage of indexes (an index with ALLTRIM() is meaningless).

Comment: @CetinBasoz . . . The values would be in the index so the index covers that portion of the query -- no data pages would need to be fetched.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please read the question. He says VFP and DBF. Indexing doesn't work like it does in MS SQL server. I assume you don't know VFP table and index structures and how ALLTRIM() expressions are stored in the index. IN VFP there is no 'covering' index.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you could do an inner join, I don’t know how fox pro handles cross joins in a cursor It sounds like the cross join is doing the damage here: 9,000 rows at 20mb in an untrimmed cross join is a lot more than 2 gigabytes but it sounds like this might help:

```
SELECT;
        DISTINCT t1.*;
        FROM t1; 
        inner join t2 on
        ALLTRIM(t1.name) = ALLTRIM(t2.name)
        AND ALLTRIM(t1.name2) = ALLTRIM(t2.name2)
        AND t1.tyc = t2.tyc
        AND t1.nc = t2.nc
        AND t1.forced = 0
        AND t1.secuence NOT in (Select secuence FROM t2)
        Into Cursor cursordel
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, and I see your logic, but, sadly, VFP seems not support this

Answer (score 0):

Why is the need for distinct in the first place? An why do you create an implicit cross join and then a filtering when all you want to do is an EXISTS check? And also, what is the the purpose of those alltrim()s? Is your fields have leading spaces? Or did you instead mean to trim trailing spaces? If the latter, it is totally unnecessary and also prevents the usage of indexes that might exist.

```
SELECT * ;
            FROM t1 ;
            WHERE t1.forced = 0 ; 
            and EXISTS (select * from t2 ;
              where t1.name == t2.name ;
                AND t1.name2  == t2.name2 ;
                AND t1.tyc == t2.tyc ;
                AND t1.nc == t2.nc ) ;
            and not EXISTS (select * from t2 where t1.secuence = t2.secuence) ;
            Into Cursor cursordel ;
            NOFILTER
```